# Scala equivalent of Haskell first and second

Tags: scala, haskell, functional-programming, mapping

Haskell has very convenient functions called `first` and `second` which apply a function to one element of a pair:

```
first fn (a,b) = (fn a, b)
second fn (a,b) = (a, fn b)
```

Are such functions defined in the standard Scala libraries?

**Edit:** I know it's easy to define them, but where possible it's cleaner to use standard functions with standard names…

```
def first[A, B, X](fn: A => X)(pair: (A, B)): (X, B) = (fn(pair._1), pair._2)
def second[A, B, X](fn: B => X)(pair: (A, B)): (A, X) = (pair._1, fn(pair._2))
```

Comment: https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/series/7.3.x/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Arrow.scala, not a standard library though

Comment: @VictorMoroz if you turn that into an answer I will accept it…

Comment: Ok, but that's not the "standard library" as the question was posed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haskell's Arrows (`first` and `second` are among them) are implemented in Scalaz:

[Scalaz source](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/series/7.3.x/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Arrow.scala)

[Some examples](http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/Arrow.html)

While it's technically not a standard library it's stable and seems to be well maintained.

**UPDATE**

Syntax is a bit cumbersome though (maybe there is another way?):

```
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._

val f = (x: Int) => x + 1
val g = f.second[String]
g("1", 2) //> ("1", 3)

// or with type inference

f second ("1", 2) //> ("1", 3)
```

Answer (score 4):

> Are such functions defined in the standard Scala libraries?

Nope. This isn't something that comes up so often in Scala that it warrants being in the standard library. It is also very difficult to generalize to tuples of any arity without an explosive amount of code (or macro).

Comment: Haskell is not generalizing it to any arity either. Arrows (that is how they are called in Haskell) can be pretty useful, and not only `first` and `second`, there are others too. It's just not a Scala way as I understand, they are implemented in Scalaz though.

Comment: @VictorMoroz, Haskell's `Arrow` class, sadly, is widely considered broken. `arr` is too powerful, and operations that could avoid it in many useful cases are missing. On the plus side, `first` and `second` are also methods of the conceptually simpler `Bifunctor` class.